# How to write the media queries for very large screens(above 4000px i.e 62 inch monitors)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, responsive

I am shucking in writing the media queries for 62 inch large screens which is of above 4000px.

Can anyone guide me how to write the media queries for the very large screens .

**.component.css**

```
 @media (max-width: 4000px){
    #map {
      width: 100%;
      
    }

    .overlay {
    position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #2d3436 0%, #000000 74%);
   opacity: 0.9;
    z-index: 1000;
    height: 700px;
 
    bottom: 0;
  }
  .overlay2 {
    position: absolute;
  width: 1500px;
  height: 2000px;
  top: 0;
/*margin-top: 57px;*/
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #2d3436 0%, #000000 74%);
  opacity: 0.6;
  overflow: auto;
  }
```

Comment: In fact, if by **above 4000px** you meant **greater than 4000px**, replace `(max-width: 4000px)` by `(min-width: 4000px)` as @Nikhil wrote it.

Comment: Thanks, but How to write it by using aspect ratio or resolution

Comment: You can use **[relative sizing](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)** : rem, %, vw, or vh for example, **instead of** defining fixed sizes with **px**. I'm not sure I well understood your question.

Comment: Thanks @Devart .But it is not working properly Can you please help me to write the responsive code using bootstrap  and  edit the above code using bootstrap  .Why because I have used the bootstrap code design   for the above overlay classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 4000px){
    #id {

      desired css
      
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please edit the code by using bootstrap responsive code.